# Create a bar diagram with matplotlib with x-axis date and width is a time-delta

Tags: python, date, numpy, datetime, matplotlib

I have a simple dataset that I would like to display in a bar chart corresponding to a weight collected at different times. I want it cumulative with an error bar I have estimated before. Since the weight corresponds to an accumulation during a certain period of time, I want the bar to be the width of the time it represents.

The entry file is in the form:

```
Date    Weight  Deviation
2017-05-04  500 100
2017-05-08  7.4 0.3
2017-05-13  6.4 0.3
2017-05-21  8.7 0.27
2017-06-06  16.8    0.7
2017-06-07  14.4    0.6
2017-06-18  13.7    0.6
2017-06-25  16.3    0.7
2017-07-02  17  0
2017-07-09  17  0
2017-07-26  20  0
2017-08-11  19  0
2017-08-23  12  0
2017-09-03  27  0
2017-09-11  15  0
2017-09-16  60  0
```

Here the code:

```
import os, sys, datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

DATA  = np.genfromtxt(Path_to_File, dtype=[('Date','datetime64[D]'),('Weight', 'float32'), ('Deviation', 'float32')], delimiter ='\t', skip_header = 1)
Days  = np.zeros(len(DATA)-1, dtype = 'datetime64[D]')
Duration = np.zeros(len(DATA)-1, dtype = 'timedelta64[D]')
for i in range(1, len(DATA)):
    DayOut = DATA[i][0]
    DayIn  = DATA[i-1][0]
    Duration[i-1] = DayOut - DayIn
    Days[i-1] = DayIn + Duration[i-1]/2


fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111)
fig2.suptitle('FigureTitle', fontsize=16)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.bar(Days, DATA['Weight'].cumsum()[1:], width=Duration, yerr = DATA['Deviation'][1:])
ax.set_ylabel('Cumulative weight (kg)')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

I get this error message

```
Cannot cast ufunc less input from dtype('<m8[D]') to dtype('<m8') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

It is tricky because I think it gets annoyed between dates(datetime64), the Days array and duration for the width (timedelta64), the Duration array. 
I am a bit stuck, I suppose I have to do a duration only axis? Any experience, or suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible because of how matplotlib works now. It converts datetime to numbers to generate x-axis. One work around is use the number of days since start as your x-axis and manually add ticks later. `ax.bar((Days-min(Days)).astype(int), DATA['Weight'].cumsum()[1:], width=Duration.astype(int), yerr = DATA['Deviation'][1:])`

Comment: @HaochenWu I do not know what should be impossible here, but manually setting labels according to a calender is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have managed to get the exact result I wanted and made the code a bit more 'pythonesque'. There were problems for consecutive dates with fraction of days, so I switched the duration format to hours and did some adjustments here and there. I also switched to a cumulative error it was more representative in my case.

```
DATA  = np.genfromtxt(WorkingDir+os.sep+File, dtype=[('Date','datetime64[D]'),('Weight', 'float32'), ('Deviation', 'float32')], delimiter ='\t', skip_header = 1)

Duration = np.diff(DATA['Date']).astype('timedelta64[h]')
Days = DATA['Date'][:-1] + Duration/2
### Trick: transform the np array 'datetime64[h]' to a list datetime.datetime
Days = [x.tolist() for x in Days]

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111)
fig2.suptitle('Cumulative weight', fontsize=16)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.bar(Days, DATA['Weight'].cumsum()[1:], width=Duration.astype(float)/24, yerr = DATA['Deviation'].cumsum()[1:], align="center", color= 'grey')
ax.set_ylabel('Cumulative weight (kg)')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
fig2.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib cannot handle numpy.datetime64 currently. It would rely on pandas for the conversion to `datetime` objects. Since here you would anyways want to set the width of the bars in days, an easy solution without the use of pandas would be to convert the dates to `datetime` (done below via `.tolist()`). The duration can be calculated by first converting the datetimes to numbers and taking their difference.

```
Days  = [x.tolist() for x in DATA["Date"]]
Duration = np.diff(mdates.date2num(Days))
```

I guess the rest of the code can stay the same, although I did not understand why you'd leave out the first element so I changed that to omitting the last (`[:-1]`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

DATA  = np.genfromtxt("data/datetabdelim.txt", dtype=[('Date','datetime64[D]'),('Weight', 'float32'), ('Deviation', 'float32')], 
                                                      delimiter ='\t', skip_header = 1)
Days  = [x.tolist() for x in DATA["Date"]]
Duration = np.diff(mdates.date2num(Days))

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(111)
fig2.suptitle('FigureTitle', fontsize=16)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
bars = ax.bar(Days[:-1], DATA['Weight'].cumsum()[:-1], width=Duration, 
              yerr = DATA['Deviation'][:-1], edgecolor="k", alpha=0.5, align="edge")
ax.set_ylabel('Cumulative weight (kg)')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
fig2.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to get the Days in the middle of the duration because that makes more sense for my data but that is not relevant for my problem. Thanks for the help! I am not too familiar with Panda but it is another motivation to explore this library.

Comment: Note that pandas is indeed a great tool, but in this special case it will not help much unfortunately, that is why I gave the solution completely without using it.